# C# Templates for Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2005

I'm looking for some template examples, such as a C# windows dialog.

Do many hackers take advantage of template files?
There are times when I'm creating dialog forms that are very similar.  I want to make all my forms look and behave consistently, without doing a lot of coping and pasting.

```
Add New Item -> My Templates
```

Comment: With the what now? Do you mean templates for custom file types, such as you get after clicking "Add new item"?

Comment: yes, when you Add new item and scroll to the bottom of the list there is a 'My Templates' header.

Comment: What does being a "hacker" have to do with it? If the title of hacker is important, I'm betting VS doesn't fit the bill. Nobody uses advanced vectoid stabilisis.


And why no upgrade to VS2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an article on creating your own Project and Project Item templates:

[Create Reusable Project And Item Templates For Your Development Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx)

Much cooler, but not exactly what you asked for is T4 (text template transformation toolkit) that allow you to do intelligent code generation during builds.  Take a look at this MSDN article for more info:

[Generating Artifacts By Using Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make the template yourself, from the first dialog you made. This will avoid the problem of having to search for a template that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of [C# code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28VS.80%29.aspx) around. They will provide scaffolding for different structures (properties, dispose pattern and more).

Here is [one source](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Code_Snippets).

Comment: cool snippets, although it's not quite what I was after.  I'm looking for dialog basecode that I can modify and use as a template file.